# How to create Quiz in modx

Tags: modx, formit, modx-templates, modx-chunks

I am new to **modx** and I have to create **multipage** **quiz** in my website.
Any suggestion will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

While there are more than one way to achieve this, a combination of [FormIt](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/formit) 
and [FormItRetriever](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/formit/formit.formitretriever) extras might just be what you need. FormIt handles the processing of your quiz forms, which includes saving the data in the cache or on the database as a JSON object. And, as the name suggests, FormItRetriever allows you to retrieve previously saved form data on a subsequent page.

Here's a quick example adapted from FormIt's docs:

**Page 1**

```
[[!FormIt?
 &submitVar=`go`
 &hooks=`spam,redirect`
 &store=`1`
 &redirectTo=`id-of-next-page`
]]
<form action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="nospam" value="" />
    <label for="qzq1">Quiz question 1: [[!+fi.error.qzq1]]</label>
    <input type="text" name="qzq1:required" id="qzq1" value="[[!+fi.qzq1]]" />
    <label for="qzq2">Quiz question 2: [[!+fi.error.qzq2]]</label>
    <input type="text" name="qzq2:required" id="qzq2" value="[[!+fi.qzq2]]" />
    <label for="qzq3">Quiz question 3: [[!+fi.error.qzq3]]</label>
    <textarea name="qzq3:stripTags" id="qzq3" cols="55" rows="7">[[!+fi.qzq3]]</textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Next" />
</form>
```

The **&store** property tells FormIt to store the data in the cache for retrieval using the FormItRetriever snippet.

The **&redirectTo** property is the ID of your next page. FormIt will use the redirect hook, specified in the **&hooks** property, to redirect the user when they submit this form.

**Page 2:**

```
[[!FormItRetriever]]

[[!FormIt?
 &submitVar=`go`
 &hooks=`spam,redirect`
 &store=`1`
 &redirectTo=`id-of-third-page`
]]

/* Page 2 quiz form goes here */
```

The FormItRetriever snippet will allow you to display your previously saved form data with placeholders relating to the names of your form fields => [!+fi.qzq1]]

To store the quiz form data on the database, you can use [FormItSaveForm](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/formit/formit.hooks/formit.hooks.formitsaveform). This allows you to later view the data inside a Custom Manager Page (CMP) and export it, if need be.

Refer to the official docs for more usage examples: https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/formit